# Edit a django.auth user via ModelForm

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I'm attempting to create a simple 'profile edit' form using the django.contrib.auth.models.User model via a ModelForm. This is what I have currently:

Form:

```
class UserEditForm(ModelForm):
    class meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(UserEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

View:

```
def edit_user(request, user):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username__exact = user)

    form = UserEditForm(request.POST or None, request=request, instance=user)

    return render_to_response('forms.html', add_csrf(request, form=form, title='Edit User'), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Logically, this seems like it should work, but the form to edit the user doesn't show up in my template when I load the page. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django already provides you helper forms for this; which you can find [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.forms).

If you still want to use your own, you need to keep in mind that the logged in user is already part of the request so you can simplify your view. Since you are already using RequestContext, you don't need to do anything else to add the CSRF code - as long as the CSRF middleware is in your settings (as pointed out by U-DON).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit(request)
   # This body will only run if the user is logged in
   # and the current logged in user will be in request.user

   edit_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
   return render_to_response('forms.html',
                             {'form':edit_form},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: The render_to_response shortcut was deprecated in Django 2.0, and is removed in Django 3.0. You can use the render shortcut instead, which was added way back in Django 1.3. The render shortcut works similarly to render_to_response, but takes request as its first argument. Change your view as follows:

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)